# Have equation, want its name

Tags: math-software

In reading journal articles (in physics), I often come across recurring equations in the Introduction sections. Sometimes they don't mention its name. For example, I come across

$$\begin{eqnarray*}

E\Psi &=& {\skew{6}{\hat}{H}}\Psi\\

i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} &=& {\skew{6}{\hat}{H}}\Psi\\

\end{eqnarray*}$$

Yes, that's the Schrödinger equation (not that I actually understand it, just got it from Wikipedia). But what if I didn't know what it is? Is there some place I can type in the equation, then I'll know what its name is? Then from there, I'll know where to start looking for more information.

Comment: Some related questions: [How to search the internet for strings that consist mostly of math notation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74609) and [How to google search mathematical notions and expressions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1055538)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try http://uniquation.com/. This is basically a tex searcher, but it is better than a full text search. For instance search for `\frac{a}{b}` returns results which contain `\frac{e}{m}`.

I believe this is still in Beta though.

Caveat: I haven't used this site much.

Answer (score 4):

I've been reasonably successful typing the latex code on google. Try googling "\hbar i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=H\psi" to see what I mean.

Edit: try without the quotes first..

Comment: It looks into the underlying TeX code in TeX-enabled websites. Not quite that Google understands what the TeX represents at all. Not exactly what I'm looking for, but this could be a step forward at least.

Comment: Obviously.. But latex is the most popular way so there are good chances of finding what you want.