# How to filter out non-mathematical results in online searching?

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

This [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055538/how-to-google-search-mathematical-notions-and-expressions) has been asked; yet I am still looking for an efficient way to filter out non-mathematical materials in an online searching. For example, is there any "mathematical" searching engine such that when I search "Johnson filtration", I will only see the term being interpreted as a mathematical subject instead of a company selling filters?

I am aware that searching "Johnson filtration mathematics" works okay with google; but I am wondering if there is any searching engine which restricts searching results completely within the realm of mathematics.

Comment: I've always been (positively) surprised that googling "word problem" does bring up the mathematical concepts (there are two) instead of threads discussing bugs in a wide-spread text processor

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes, google shows some respect to mathematics; but I am wondering if there is any "mathematical" searching engine.